# If/else with Event Listeners beginner JavaScript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, attachevent

I read that attach.event is only used in early versions of IE. I was wondering why it is used here, it seems to correspond to executing the populateFigures() part of the setUpPage() function, is this correct? I really appreciate any help!

```
function setUpPage() {
createEventListeners();
populateFigures();

}//end of setUpPage Function


/* run setUpPage() function when page finishes loading */

if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener("load", setUpPage, false); 
} else if (window.attachEvent)  {
      window.attachEvent("onload", setUpPage);
}//end of else if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is correct.

It is just to make sure that `onload` should work in IE (6 to 10) becuase of limited support of `addEventListener` in these versions of IE.

> `attachEvent` is a proprietary Microsoft Internet Explorer alternative
>   to the standard EventTarget.addEventListener() method.

So your code is checking if property `addEventListener` is present in the `window` object then add an event using `addEventListener` otherwise if the property `attachEvent` exists (primarily on IEs) on window object then add event using `addEventListener`.

Read more about [attachEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/attachEvent) here.

Comment: Thank you so much!